# JavaScript trying to change image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

There are four files at the same folder directory

```
- 1.jpg 
- 2.jpg 
- index.html 
- 1.js
```

I am hoping to write the code so it will load `1.jpg` at first, but it will load `2.jpg` next

The JavaScript is

```
var img = new Image();   // Create new img element
img.src = '2.jpg';


var getElementIMG = document.getElementById("imageid");
getElementIMG.src = img.src;
```

And the HTML is

```
<img id="imageid" src="1.jpg">
```

but when the page finishes loading it still displays `1.jpg`

Comment: What is the empty image element for? `document.getElementById("imageid").src = '2.jpg';`, and make sure you place the script after the elements in the DOM.

Comment: Are you sure this piece of code is being called? Did you try to debug it? Where in the page did you place it?

Comment: When and where are you calling the javascript?

Comment: <head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
</head>

Comment: try to post question with all information, as someone can easily answer ur question just after reading.

Comment: Move the script tag to right before `</body>`

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="showstopper" src="1.jpg">
</body>

document.getElementById("showstopper").src = '2.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
       <body>
          <img id="imageid" src="1.jpg">
          <script>
              var getElementIMG = document.getElementById("imageid");
              getElementIMG.src = '2.jpg';
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Javascript` is on the `header` you need to specify when do you want the `image` to be replaced, which is when it exists.

After the `window` has been loaded:

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("imageid").src = "2.jpg";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5a6Jx/2/

Or you can just stick the `script` at the end of the page:

```
<img id="imageid" src="1.jpg" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("imageid").src = "2.jpg";
</script>
```

On both ways your `image` will be there already, so you can manipulate it.

Comment: Is it always a good idea to load JavaScript files AFTER running the HTML file?

Comment: To keep things separated, I always put everything on a `.js` file and load on the `header`. You just need to work out when the `element` will be there to play around with it. But that's a personal choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head> <script type="text/javascript" src="1.js"></script> </head>
```

The script is loaded in the head and executed immediately. There is no element '#imageid', so `document.getElementById` returns `null`. An error is probably thrown on the `getElementIMG.src = img.src;` line. If something doesn't work, one of the first things you should do is check for errors in the debugger/console. (F12 in most browsers.)
Later on the page, the browser sees an image. It displays it.

What you want to do is load the script after the image. If you put it at the end of the page, the `<img>` will be seen by the browser, and only after that, its `src` will be changed.

Comment: Is it always a good idea to load javascript files AFTER loading the HTML?

Comment: The easiest way to avoid trouble is to put all javascript files before the closing `</body>` tag. As a bonus, your page will load faster -- JS is only downloaded when the rest of the page is displayed.

Comment: The total load times might be about the same, but the page will definitely show faster. JS files are not needed to render your page, so the browser doesn't wait for them to finish before rendering. (Except if they're halfway your page, because the scripts might contain things like `document.write` that need to be inserted at that exact point)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make your move when the document and your image are both loaded.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = '2.jpg';

    img.onload = function() {
        var getElementIMG = document.getElementById("imageid");
        getElementIMG.src = img.src;
     }
}
```